# Need to create single WSClient object in a custom class as property of that custom class through DI in play-2.5.

Tags: java

We are using play2.5 with java. I have a custom class i.e. class A, in which I have injected a WSClient object as the property of custom class A through DI. We create multiple instances of this custom class A, so with every new instance of custom class A we get a new instance of WSClient. Our requirement is there should be only single instance of WSClient among multiple instance of the custom class A. So I used @Singleton annotation of javax.inject above the property of WSClient. But it doesn't create singleton instance, it creates a new instance of WSClient every time whenever I instatiate my custom class A. Can any one suggests some sol to create the single instance of WSClient in my custom class A ? 
Below is the code snippet:

```
class A {

private final WSRequest holder;

@Singleton
public WSClient wsClient = Play.current().injector().instanceOf(WSClient.class);

 A(String url) {
    holder = wsClient.url(url);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can create wsclient singleton outside this class and use that inside this class. Similar to spring framework singleton bean with autowire capability.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use Spring framework

2) Declare wsclient as bean with default singleton scope

[Declaring Bean](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html)

3) Use [autowire](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_autowired_annotation.htm) capability of spring to inject the bean wsclient into class A

Comment: notionquest, thanks for answer, I have tried this, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mean it creates multiple instances of wsclient? you need to send the wsclient as constructor argument to class A. Will try to add some sample in a while.